# How do I pass variable inside find and bash -c?

Tags: bash

I have issues with passing variable to %exe part of the code.

Here is my working code that I use inside bash script:

```
## Function
targz() {
  find $1 -type f -name "*.$2" -exec \
    bash -c 'old=$(basename {}); new=${old/%exe/tar\.gz}; \
      tar -zcvf $new $old; ' \;
}

## Function Call
## targz [directory] [extension]
targz . 'exe';
```

and yes I've tried using it some thing like this:

```
new=${old/%$2/tar\.gz};
```

but it generates filenames like: file.exetar.gz .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
targz() {
  find $1 -type f -name "*.$2" -exec \
    bash -c 'old=$(basename {}); new=${old/'"$2"'/tar\.gz}; \
      tar -zcvf $new $old; ' \;
}
```

The trick is to get out of the single quote, so that variable expansion will be performed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `env` to set an environment variable for `bash`:

```
targz() {
  find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2" -exec \
    env ext="$2" bash -c 'old=$(basename "{}"); new=${old/%$ext/tar\.gz}; \
      tar -zcvf "$new" "$old"; ' \;
}
```

I added some quoting to protect against spaces in filenames.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, I've applied the double quotes around {}

Comment: Nice; It's also worth double-quoting `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: `{}` is not meant to be used that way; your command is subject to code injection (file named `"); find / -delete; a=("` would have a rather funny effect. Instead: use `{}` as so: `... -exec bash -c 'old=$(basename "$0") ...' {} \;` By the way, I don't really see the use of `env` here. Either use `$2` as another argument to `bash`, or use it as an environment variable once for all: `ext=$2 find ...`. Also, with `bash`, you can really do without `basename`.