# Is there an advantage to using env for setting variable for a subshell?

Tags: bash

I recently came across some samples which set an environment variable and launch a subprocess in the same command:

```
$ TEST="test" sh -c 'echo $TEST"
```

Previously, I had always used env for that:

```
$ env TEST="test" sh -c 'echo $TEST"
```

Can someone point me at the explanation of the first example?
Is there any advantage to using env for this?

Comment: The only thing I've ever used `env` for is to set environment variables with funny names to test programs and to see them break miserably; e.g., `env $'a\nb=c' program`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few reasons to use `env`. Most of the time you can (and should) use the simpler syntax:

```
var=value ... command
```

which is Posix standard, and should be available in any Posix compatible shell (including `/bin/sh`).

Here are a few cases in which `env` is useful:

1. The above syntax does not work in `csh` (or derivatives), nor does it work in `fish`. So in these non-Posix shells, `env` is required for local environment modifications.
2. The `-i` argument to `env` starts the indicated command with an environment containing *only* the specified environment variables. This can be used to run an untrusted command without leaking information through environment variables. (But be careful: some environment variables must be set for normal functioning, starting with `PATH`.)
3. `env` resolves the name of the command to an executable using the `PATH` environment variable, possibly modified in the `env` command line. In a context where pathname resolution is not performed (shebang lines, for example), using `env` (with the correct full filepath) saves having to know the precise paths for all other possible executables. (It is for this reason that it is frequently encountered in shebang lines).
4. The arguments to `env` are expanded by the shell before env is invoked. Consequently, it is possible to also compute the *name* of an environment variable, something which is not possible using the standard shell syntax:

   ```
   env "$name=$value" command ...
   ```

   This is particularly useful when expanding an environment from an array (in bash):

   ```
   env -i "${new_env[@]}" command ...
   ```

   (Here, `new_env` is expected to be an array of the form `(var1=val1 var2=val2 ...)` )
5. `env` without a command will print the (possibly modified) environment out, one environment variable per line. I don't find this feature all that useful, but it's in the Posix rationale for the continued existence of the `env` utility:

   > Some have suggested that env is redundant since the same effect is achieved by:
   >
   > name=value ... utility [ argument ... ]
   >
   > The example is equivalent to env when an environment variable is being added to the environment of the command, but not when the environment is being set to the given value. The env utility also writes out the current environment if invoked without arguments. There is sufficient functionality beyond what the example provides to justify inclusion of env.

Comment: If not using the `-i` option, `eval "${new_env[@]} command …"` would work too, but I agree that using `env` is cleaner.

Comment: @5gon12eder Unfortunately your `eval` line doesn't work in the following cases: if the variable names contain spaces or characters that can't be part of a variable name in Bash; more importantly if the fields contain spaces or other funny symbols. As such, your line is subject to code injection: `new_env[@]=( "env_var=hello rm -rf *" )` would be handled in a rather unfunny way with your method.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: ah, true. And your comment is more precise. The `-i` in my example wasn't accidental, though. It assumed that the environment array had been constructed as a complete environment, for example as a selection from the standard environment.

Answer (score 3):

One important use for `env` is with the `find` command.

This will *not* work:

```
find . -exec f={} somecommand \;  # Won't work
```

This will work:

```
find . -exec env f={} somecommand \;
```

The reason is that `find` wants the first argument after `-exec` to be an executable and `env` satisfies that requirement.

#### Example

A related example showing the convenience of using `env` with `find` is this function from [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4315716/3030305):

```
targz() {
  find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2" -exec \
    env ext="$2" bash -c 'old=$(basename "{}"); new=${old/%$ext/tar\.gz}; \
      tar -zcvf "$new" "$old"; ' \;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific use case of this with `find`? Besides, this is not portable, as [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) _If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change._

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Good point re POSIX compliance. In practice, both _GNU_ `find` and _BSD_ `find` DO expand `{}` in this scenario.

Comment: The example is interesting, and I know that you quoted it verbatim, but I encourage you to double-quote `$1` and `$2` for robustness.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for catching that.  Correction made.

Comment: Thanks for updating; I see that you correctly also double-quoted `$2`, which, as I just realized, is a _must_ with with values with embedded whitespace _when using  `env`_, whereas it is _optional_ when using the shell's `var=<val> command ...` mechanism.

Comment: Why is it really convenient to use `env` here like so? I mean, you can use `ext=$2 find ...` directly. It might be more efficient too. Or even you can pass this as an extra argument to `bash`: `find ... -exec bash -c '...' "$2" {}`.

Answer (score 1):

`env` is a program that calls (as a forked subprocess) the provided command with the provided arguments, passing the accumulated environment to the command.

`TEST="test"` is a feature supported by the shell (such as `bash`).  In most cases it has the same effect as `env TEST="test"` but without the `env` process running as a middleman.

Since nearly all modern shells support `TEST="test"` it is generally safe to use that approach.

Comment: The syntax is not a bash extension. It's required by any Posix shell (2.1.3 "A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator) and was present in the first Bourne shell (1977 or so).

Comment: Oops. The cited Posix sentence is in XSH, section 2.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there are some old or obscure shells that do not support the first syntax (`TEST=test sh`).  You have to use a separate utility like `env` to set an environment variable for a child process if you want your script to work in such a shell.

Comment: csh and tcsh do not use that syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Aren't `csh` and `tcsh` covered by 'obscure shells'?